# How to get LU file from LUIS.AI portal

Tags: azure-language-understanding

It seems like this would be obvious but I cannot find anything about this on either my search engines or Stack Overflow, nor the LUIS documentation in both Microsoft and Github.

How do I get the LU (.lu file extension) file from the entities and intents I made inside the luis.ai portal? I don't have a JSON file to generate it from, I already made my models inside the portal. I just want to export from the portal into a LU file.

I want to know how the difference between {@entity=blabla} and {entity=blabla} in the lu file format but that's not documented. I figured an example from my own models would help.

Comment: To export you app in .lu format,
- go to you applications page, 
- select your application
- in the top bar click on the "Export" dropdown 
- select "Export as LU"

Comment: That worked, if you put it as the answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To export you app in .lu format, - go to you applications page, - select your application - in the top bar click on the "Export" dropdown - select "Export as LU"